# how to fix ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i had installed python 3.6.5 and pycharm community version 2020.1.2 on windows 8.1 pro..it works completely fine on numpy but when i imported pandas,it shows error....please help me to get out of this problem.....
it just show this...
C:\Users\india\Desktop\final\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/india/Desktop/final/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/india/Desktop/final/test.py", line 1, in 
    import pandas
  File "C:\Users\india\Desktop\final\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas__init__.py", line 55, in 
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "C:\Users\india\Desktop\final\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 29, in 
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg
  File "C:\Users\india\Desktop\final\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby__init__.py", line 1, in 
    from pandas.core.groupby.generic import DataFrameGroupBy, NamedAgg, SeriesGroupBy
  File "C:\Users\india\Desktop\final\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 60, in 
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "C:\Users\india\Desktop\final\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 124, in 
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "C:\Users\india\Desktop\final\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4572, in 
    Series._add_series_or_dataframe_operations()
  File "C:\Users\india\Desktop\final\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 10349, in _add_series_or_dataframe_operations
    from pandas.core.window import EWM, Expanding, Rolling, Window
  File "C:\Users\india\Desktop\final\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window__init__.py", line 1, in 
    from pandas.core.window.ewm import EWM  # noqa:F401
  File "C:\Users\india\Desktop\final\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\ewm.py", line 5, in 
    import pandas._libs.window.aggregations as window_aggregations
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same problem. By default, pip installs the version **1.0.3**. I reverted it back to version **1.0.1**

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas==1.0.1
```

This worked for me. Try it.

Comment: Downgrading to 1.0.1 worked for me on Python 3.7.0 and Windows Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Install all pending updates and retry.
I experienced same error before where I couldn't import seaborn and train_test_split module from sklearn.model.
I tried many fixes I found online but  didn't work,
I discovered that I have many pending windows updates so I downloaded and installed all pending updates and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with windows 8, I solved it by adding the C:\Windows\System32 folder to PATH.